# Utilizando ElasticSearch, como obter dados entre determinado intervalo de horas utilizando range

Tags: query, elasticsearch

Olá, estou utilizando ElasticSearch, e minha query não está buscando as informações que eu quero.

```
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {
            "must": 
            [
                {
                    "range": 
                    {
                       "date": 
                       {
                           "gte": "2016-04-29 00:00:01",
                           "lte": "now"
                       }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Já tentei algumas variações, como colocar:

```
"lte": "2016-04-29 23:59:59"
```

Porém não adianta, o resultado é todas as datas possíveis, basicamente é como se essa query nem existisse. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer pegar dados com a data maior que 29/04/2016?

Comment: Isso, quero as datas entre 2016-04-29 00:00:01 e 2016-04-29 23:59:59, ou seja, quero as informações cadastradas no dia de hoje

Answer (score 3):

Talvez o problema de não retornar os documentos filtrados esteja relacionado com a formatação do tipo `datetime` indexado.

Testei sua query e o resultado foi como o esperado, retornou os documentos filtrados pelo intervalo de datas, a única alteração foi a inclusão da clausula `format`.

Caso o `format` não seja utilizado os parâmetros de pesquisas devem ter a mesma formatação das propriedades presente nos documentos indexados.

```
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {
            "must": 
            [
                {
                    "range": 
                    {
                       "my_property_date": 
                       {
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                            "gte": "2016-04-29 00:00:01",
                            "lte": "now"
                       }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Clique aqui para saber mais sobre o format | Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/mapping-date-format.html)